# Problems with list<T> in Asp.Net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making a web app in Asp.Net using c# that lets you add items into the list.

My problem is that each time that i click the button to add a new item into the list , its just shows me the last item and the list counter shows me only 1 .

What am I doing wrong??

Here is the code :

```
public partial class home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 List<string> messageboxs = new List<string>();
 public string val = "";
 public string data = "";

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    val = "";
    messageboxs.Add(text1.Text);
    ListBox1.DataSource = messageboxs;
    ListBox1.DataBind();
    val = messageboxs.Count.ToString();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read up on [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). In a nut shell, everytime you click the button it causes the page to postback which creates a new instance of the page. You are initializing an empty list on each instance of that page therefore when you come to adding the new item into the list...it's empty again.

What you need to do is store `messageboxs` somewhere which will allow it to persist across postbacks. For your particular example, you could use the [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) e.g.

```
public partial class home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            // initialise list
            ViewState["Messages"] = new List<string>();
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // get the old messages list
        var messages = (List<string>)ViewState["Messages"];
        messages.Add(text1.Text);
        ListBox1.DataSource = messages;
        ListBox1.DataBind();
        // store the new messages list
        ViewState["Messages"] = messages;
    }   
}
```

Comment: why iam getting an error when i replace the list type from string to an object type ??

Comment: @JohnathanNardia the ViewState serializes the data and stores it in the page itself so you need to mark your class as `Serializable`. Be wary though, if it's a pretty complex object with references etc. consider storing it in the `Session` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Your list is not persisted between postbacks.

Every time you click a button a new instance of the page class and therefore list is created. This list is empty.

Comment: I think debugging and understanding the pitfall would have been better in the long run.

Comment: sorry how can presised between postbacks. ?

Comment: @JohnathanNardia - check my answer. I spent a bit more time (at the cost of the most votes for posting right away) and posted the root cause and solution. If you want more detail, let me know.

Comment: Could downvoters explain what is wrong with my answer please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how ASP.Net works. ASP.Net is recreating your "home" page on each button click. This then recreates the list, and you add one item to it. You need a way to save the list between button clicks. That's what, for example, the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is for.

Answer (score 0):

The list is created again on each postback. You should look at going through the existing items in `ListBox1` and re-adding them to your `List<string>` then re-binding.

Answer (score 0):

Make your messageboxs static variable as

static List messageboxs = new List();

But this makes the variable accessible from any page request.
meaning if someone else open this page and tried to add an item he/she will end up adding an item to someone else's list.

try using session state or view state instead.